# Referencing a compressed payload for the managed bootstrapper application prerequisite eula

Tags: wix, wix3.7, burn

I'm building a setup bundle which needs to work in a non-internet connected environment, so I am including the .NET 4.0 framework installer, and its corresponding eula in the bundle. I copied the source from `wix37-sources\src\ext\NetFxExtension\wixlib\NetFx4.wxs` but with some modifications so that the package is compressed instead of a remote payload.

However, I haven't been able to figure out how to make the eula link load the payload from the bundle. I always get:

```
[0930:0BDC][2013-08-22T16:02:37]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to launch URL to EULA.
```

Here's the wix source:

```
<!-- Referencing the NetFx40Full package will cause these WixVariables to be defined -->
<!-- which indicates to the bootstrapper engine what the MBA dependency is -->
<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="NetFx40Full"/>
<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="NetFX_4_all_FINAL_RTM.rtf"/>

<PackageGroup Id="NetFx40Full">
  <ExePackage
      Id="NetFx40Full"
      InstallCommand="/q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot;"
      RepairCommand="/q /norestart /repair /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot;"
      UninstallCommand="/uninstall /q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot;"
      PerMachine="yes"
      DetectCondition="NETFRAMEWORK40"
      Vital="yes"
      Permanent="yes"
      Protocol="netfx4"
      SourceFile="$(var.SourceRoot)\Deployment\Packages\.NET Framework 4.0\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
      Compressed="yes">

    <Payload SourceFile="$(var.SourceRoot)\Deployment\Packages\.NET Framework 4.0\NetFX_4_all_FINAL_RTM.rtf"
             Compressed="yes"/>
  </ExePackage>
</PackageGroup>
```

Is this actually possible?